# Genus = 2 in closed bosonic string theory

Tags: string-theory

In https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(86)90761-6

For p1,
1.) Does "$D_q$" mean "$D_q$ module"? or "Deformation quantization module"?

For p2,
how to explain that
2.) "at the infinity $D_0$" is equivalent to "where ${T}_{11}$ of ${T}_{22}$ tends to $i\infty$" (if anyone think these two character strings "at the infinity ${D}_{0}$" and "where ${T}_{11}$ of ${T}_{22}$ tends to $i\infty$" are connected.)

and (hence)
3.) "at the infinity ${D}_{0}$ (where ${T}_{11}$ of ${T}_{22}$ tends to $i\infty$), the measure
$\prod_{i\le j}^{2}{dT}_{ij}$ has a first order pole"?
4.)"a first order zero at ${D}_{0}$ and a double zero at ${D}_{1}$" is equivalent to "where ${T}_{12}$ \to 0" (if anyone thinks these two character strings "a first order zero at ${D}_{0}$ and a double zero at ${D}_{1}$" and "where ${T}_{12}$ \to 0" are connected.)
5.) Does $\prod_{i\le j}^{2}{dT}_{ij}[{\chi}_{12-p}(T)]^{-1}$ imply that has a first order zero at ${D}_{0}$ and a double zero at ${D}_{1}$(where ${T}_{12} \to 0$) ?
(p.s. even if trying to find the reference https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/html/1509.00830,  I still don't understand 2.) 3.) 4.) 5.) )

Comment: Your MathJax is not rendering properly because you are not enclosing it in \$…\$.

Comment: That article is behind a paywall, so most of us can’t read it.

Comment: @Ghoster I've just checked, you can read it.

Comment: This doesn’t look anything like the way physicists write physics. You should be using \$…\$ for “inline” math and \$\$…\$\$ only for math that needs to be displayed on a line of its own.

Comment: @Ghoster Thanks for your teaching operaion of code command I should use after I posted the question at the first time.

Comment: It looks so much better now! I wish I could answer your question, but I haven’t studied string theory.